# PerfMon Metrics Collector cant connection

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a database in a docker container, I have created an api to get data from the database. I want to see the performance of the database in using cpu, memory, i/o, and network.

Therefore I use http request as sampler and jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector as listener, but when I run this test, I get an error message, like this

00:38:36 - ERROR: java.net.ConnectException: Connection denied: connecting (in jmeter)

and this message from my running api terminal

127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2024 00:58:58] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('test')
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2024 00:58:58]"test" 400 -

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

PerfMon Metrics Collector should not be targeting your "API".

What you need to do is:

1. Install [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) to the host you want to monitor
2. Run it
3. Configure PerfMon Metrics Collector to use hostname or IP address of the machine you want to monitor and the default port `4444`, not the one where your API lives

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)